# Apache-Nifi : Delete MongoDB collections

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I want to delete some collections : `db['mycollection'].remove({})` ,of my MongoDB database, i found out that there is a deleteMongo processor but i don't know how to use it since i can't find examples.

So, does deleteMongo processor allow to do this? if it does, can you show me an example please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The `DeleteMongo` doesn't actually delete collections, rather it deletes the documents in the provided collection. Take a look at the processor's documentation [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mongodb-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.mongodb.DeleteMongo/index.html). It expects the incoming FlowFile to have the query as its content. A quick example you could try is:

```
GenerateFlowFile -> DeleteMongo
```

Configure `GenerateFlowFile` and provide a MongoDB query, something like `{ "customer.name" : "Smith, John"}` and connect it to `DeleteMongo`. You have to configure `DeleteMongo` with the database name, connection string and collection name.

Having said that, it may not suit your requirement of dropping collections, but technically you can wipe the entire collection of documents from the configured collection, if your query is `{}` and the `Delete Mode` of DeleteMongo processor is set to `Delete Many`

Comment: Thank you, i have also a python script to remove the collections, and i'm trying to use it in the ExecuteScript processor. do you know how i could do this?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but the documentation should help you in doing this.