# Apache Nifi: First Delete entries then Insert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I want to empty a collection before inserting incoming documents. The collection should always reflect the exact same documents, as the ones coming into the processor.

I tried PutMongo with `Mode: update`, which will not delete entries which are not part of the incoming documents.

I tried a combination of DeleteMongo and PutMong with `Mode: insert`. But also here, DeleteMongo only deletes entries matching to the incoming documents.

I probably have to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50874847/1071828 and use `GenerateFlowFile({}) -> DeleteMongo` to delete all entries of he collection. This has to happen before PutMongo. How do I chain those processors and send the original incoming documents to PutMongo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Wait and Notify](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/) processors for this case.

```
1. Wait(before PutMongoDB processor)- Until delete happens in MongoDB then insert into MongoDB

2. Notify(after DeleteMongoDB processor)- Once deletes is completed in MongoDB collection then Notify the Wait processor to release the flowfile.
```

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I need. Thanks! Will try it later.

Comment: So I've been playing with wait and notify, but I can't really figure which release identifiers and counts to use in this case. I've been trying a single string "DONE", which seemed like it accepted alle messages, including the the notification itself. Could somebody provide a simple example?